# 1 inch has Solidity interfaces for smart contract interactions?

Tags: swaps, 1inch-dex-aggregator

As of my last knowledge  1inch provides a set of APIs for interacting with its services, but it may not have a direct Solidity interface for smart contract interactions. Instead, developers typically use the 1inch API to access its features programmatically. And basically  I want to  integrate the 1inch swap function into my  existing contract.
SO anyone help me how can i do this1inch has interfaces for itneractiing with its servies please send me reference where this thing is going on?